# unexpected token: javascript syntax error using object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use an object from another javascript file and I have imported the function from the other javascript file. Anyone knows what is wrong with my syntax?

```
unexpected token 

  29 |   render() {
  30 |     return (
> 31 |       const posts = this.state.posts.map((post)=>
     |       ^
  32 |         <Post url= {post.url}/>);
  33 |     );
  34 |   }
```

Comment: You cannot put one statement into another. `return` expects an expression.

Comment: Declare `const` inside render and outside return

Comment: Move line 31 between 29 and 30

Answer (score 1):

When you `return` something, you return a value or a result of an expression. What you tried to return here was a variable declaration, which is a statement. So I think if you just return the part after the equal sign, it will work:

```
render() {
  return this.state.posts.map(post =>
    <Post url={post.url} />
  );
}
```

I'm actually a beginner in React, but I think it'll work.